# DTO vs VO vs BO vs EJB?

Tags: java, java-ee

Viendo algunos ejemplo de internet vi que hay aplicaciones donde hacen una separacion de capas desde cuando se hace una peticion hasta cuando se persite en una DB?  existe un real difinicion de estos terminos? ya que he visto que cada usuario le da un enfoque distinto principalmente entre si es lo mismo VO y DTO o si un EJB seria considerado un BO?.

Comment: te sugiero leer [ask] esto parece muy basado en opiniones

Comment: No creo que solamente este basado en opinones, estos terminos existen y se utiliza en aplicaciones reales, mi pregunta viene solo con la idea de clarificar un poco mas sobre cuando usarlos en el workflow de un aplicacion.

Comment: lo comprendo y solo trato de apoyarte por lo cual yo recomiendo mejorar la redacción para que tu pregunta sea mas clara

Comment: La pregunta es muy amplia. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VO: Significa `Value Object` y es un objeto Java Bean enfocado en la vista. Basicamente es un `POJO (Plain old java object).`

BO: Significa `Business Object` y generalmente son los Java Beans que se mapean a entidades de base de datos (Objetos de negocio) como por ejemplo en Hibernate.

Generalmente se usan BO en un `patrón DAO (Data Access Object)` construido sobre un `patrón ORM (Object-Relational mapping)` para señalar que las clases BO que contienen la lógica del negocio (el acceso a la BD). Estas clases BO, si logran ser accedidas al publicarse en un API generarían mucha inseguridad ya que proporcionan en al acceso a la base de datos. Por ello generalmente las clases BO se copian en clases VO donde los VO ya no cuentan con acceso directo a la BD y pueden ser expuestos en APIs publicas sin generar fallos de seguridad.

DTO: Significa `Data Transfer Object` Un objeto de transferencia de datos es un objeto que transporta datos entre procesos. La motivación para su uso es que la comunicación entre procesos generalmente se realiza recurriendo a interfaces remotas (por ejemplo, servicios web), donde cada llamada es una operación costosa.

Un `EJB (Enterprise Java Bean)` es un java bean que gestiona eventos configurados mediante anotaciones o mediante XML. Si el EJB gestiona acceso a base de datos podría llamarse BO si sigue el patrón de diseño correspondiente. `Los EJBs son una API completa` que es competencia de otros frameworks, por ejemplo `spring`.

No domino muy bien los conceptos pero en esta pagina puedes encontrar una mejor explicación: [Patrones de diseño en java mvc dao y dto](https://www.ecodeup.com/patrones-de-diseno-en-java-mvc-dao-y-dto/)

El siguiente código es un ejemplo:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public ArrayList<BancoDTO> listar() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("llegue a banco service");

        ArrayList<Banco> bancos = bancoDAO.getAll();
        ArrayList<BancoDTO> listaDTO = new ArrayList<BancoDTO>();
        for (Banco banco : bancos) {
            System.out.println(banco.getIdBanco()+" - "+banco.getNombre());
            BancoDTO bancoDTO = new BancoDTO();
            bancoDTO.setIdBanco(banco.getIdBanco());
            bancoDTO.setNombre(banco.getNombre());
            listaDTO.add(bancoDTO);
        }

        return listaDTO;
    }
```

El objeto bancoDAO es el objeto que accede a una entidad de base de datos (una tabla). Como es una operación **select** (`bancoDAO.getAll()`) el metodo entero se anota con una transaccion de solo lectura (`@Transactional(readOnly = true)`). Este método pertenece a un web Service `System.out.println("llegue a banco service");` por lo que el objeto bancoDAO no se expone publicamente si no que se copia en un DTO (`BancoDTO bancoDTO = new BancoDTO();`) y este objeto es el que se expone publicamente.

Al final de cuentas todo esto son convenciones (como la de los setters y getters) pero varios frameworks las siguen y nada te obliga a usarlas pero si usas algun framework que las siga y tu no, podría no funcionarte lo que hagas en dicho framework.